# Where can I find "Enable access log" option in ststistics module?

Tags: 8, nodes

In drupal 7 statistics configuration page, there is all option are available for module, like as shown in following image.

**D7,**

> [image]

While in case of drupal 8 statistics configuration page there is only one option,

**D8,**

> [image]

Where can I find that configuration setting? I did check, [statistics module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/statistics/overview) page on drupal.org, but it is to be updated and not mentioning about drupal 8. Thanks

Comment: You are correct @Smalution

Comment: “Enable access log” option in statistics module has been removed in Drupal 8. For more see this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1446956)

Comment: @Anil Oh, Sad to see it has been removed, Now for just seeing IP address of visitor, we need to install GA or Piwik and both module require, many Privacy Policy Regulations to be written for site, particularly GA.